# Drupal different theme for arabic and english

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I created a drupal website in English, now i want to add an Arabic version to this site. I have added and enabled the i18n modules and now i have language switch options in my content creation and editing page in the admin.I want to show different themes for English and Arabic(for example mytheme and mytheme-ar). But how can i set drupal to show themes according to the URL , for example to show mytheme-ar, when the URL is example.com/ar and to show mytheme when example.com.

Can anybody suggest a solution? I have tried setting a cookie and setting the theme from includes/theme.inc according to the cookie. But I think there will be a more direct solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ThemeKey module](http://drupal.org/project/themekey). It can change the theme determined by complex (or simple) rules you create.